# Magento2 : Display two table column values in single UI grid column

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

I am working on admin custom module. My module table join with customer table.

Now I want to display User Name (customer firstname and lastname) values in single column in my custom module UI grid.

How can it will be done? Any one have idea?

Thanks

Comment: follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159658/magento-2-how-can-we-get-custom-value-from-custom-table-in-product-grid

Comment: Do you need a filter for this column?

Comment: First need to display in gird.

Comment: You can use custom column render, but in this case filter can not work properly without modifications in collection.

Comment: How to render custome column in grid?

Comment: How to render custom column with filter and search in admin grid using UI Component

Answer (score 6):

Little late on the answer, but hopefully helpful to those that finds this question.

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<column name="fullname" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FullName">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- You can change this accordingly -->
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Full Name</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Fullname.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class FullName extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components = []
     * @param array $data = []
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])){
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item){
                $item['fullname'] = $item['firstname'] . ' ' . $item['lastname'];

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

What is going on is that you are looping through all of the records for the grid listing, and applying data to the `fullname` column of the grid with the data `firstname` and `lastname` fields of your model.

Comment: what to do for filter working

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your UI component column like:

```
<column name="customer_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customer">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Now create renderer class Customer[Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customer]

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Customer extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @param array $item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function prepareItem(array $item)
    {
        // make your logic and return string

        return $customerName;
    }
}
```