# Add column to gridview in custom extension

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, grid-layout

I have a custom extension where the admin user needs to select a customer from the drop down. The extension saves the customer ID to the database.

Currently, on the grid view, in my UI component I have the following:

```
 <column name="customer_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer ID</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

This displays the customer id as expected.

However, my question is how do actually display the customer name instead of just the ID in the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your own **custom class** in order to get and display the **firstname** and the **lastname** of the customer in one UI column field, otherwise you can either use only one of them.
Like below code:

```
<column name="customer_firstname">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Firstname</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: How would you define my own custom class and what would be the contents?

Comment: You can check like this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178286/magento2-display-two-table-column-values-in-single-ui-grid-column?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The issue with this method though I would have to do logic on each row? I was thinking if I join in the customer_entity table then the extension would be more efficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah you are right with that I can agree.